# Propostions examples

Tags: logic

I am learning about propositions types and I was wondering if someone could briefly explain to me `Types and Tokes`, and provide example of two sentence tokens that are not of the same type. Also provide two sentences that are different types but express the same proposition. Thanks!

Comment: This should be easy if you are familiar with object-oriented programming.  It is the difference between class and object.  Also, you should try to include a summary of what you have so far done to understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : *Type* corresponds to *concept*. *Token* corresponds to *instance* or *example*.

Thus, *species* is a type while *human* is a token.

Try to form a proposition about species that uses two different tokens.

Comment: 1) Birds can fly, 2) Can birds fly? would that be an example of two sentence tokens that are not of the same type? By the way I am studying symbolic logic and the book doesn't cover this topic enough.

Comment: @Questions Each sentence in your example uses the same token "bird" and the same implied type.  Try the type "colour".  My favourite colour is blue while your favourite colour may be red.  That is 1 sentence with 2 different tokens (red, blue) of the same type (colour).

Comment: 1) my favorite food is fish 2) my favorite drink is water ... would that work as two sentence tokens of not the same type?

Comment: @Questions Yes.  That works.  You have also declared the different types (food, drink).  The tokens being fish and water.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand tokens and types. Now can you help me come up with two sentences that are different types but express the same proposition?

Comment: Maybe, 1) I like to watch movies for fun 2) I like to play soccer for fun ?

Comment: @Questions A "type" is a concept, not a sentence.  Do you mean two sentences that use different types to express the same proposition?  It is not clear how this can be done since the propositions would necessarily express different concepts (types).  You could maybe do it if the two types were of a common type.  E.g. I am a caucasian man.  I am an african man.  Both express the proposition that I am of "type" human, but they do this by using different types of human.